# Blender zooms in when rendering

Tags: rendering, scale

I know there are lots of questions about this, but I've tried all the given solutions and I'm still having the same issue. When I look at the marked area in the preview window, it shows the whole image, yet when I render, it crops the window to only show about 50% of the whole image for a couple of my video clips- but not all of them. I did some cropping and scaling of all my images, yet their appearance in the preview is how I'd like them to render.

I've checked that the resolution is the same for the image and the render (1280x720) and I've checked that the scale is 100%. Any ideas? Thanks so much!

p.s. The answer might be obvious- this is my first time using blender as a video editor, so thanks in advance for your patience!

Here's a link to my blender file: [image]

[image]

Comment: Having trouble where you mean to upload my .blend file. Is it possible to do it through this thread? (Sorry this is my first time using blender and posting here)